# Google account differs from other accounts

Tags: google-chrome, images, user-accounts, google-accounts

This is a weird issue and can't find any information online.

When we log into the one account (right-side), and search for images - the images load with low quality and the **"more like this"** section links doesn't work. All the links starts with `https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/xxx`. But literally the same exact search on the same computer in `incognito mode` or with another account (left-side), everything works fine:

[image]

Notice the image quality on the left vs the right (broken account).

Whats even more weird is that the navigation links at the top differs only on this one account (right-side):

[image]

Trying to solve this seems impossible. We have compared the entire settings screen on both the left and right, removed all extensions, themes and everything, deleted cookies, browsing data, etc. to no avail.

The same account on the Android phone does exactly the same with the links in images and also shows poor quality images.

Logged in with the same account on a different PC, and the exact same behavior occurs.

Tried `chrome://settings/reset`, deleted all `Google` site data and nothing changes.

It just started happening all of a sudden yesterday (15 Feb 2024) and can't figure it out.

No matter what we try, it only occurs on this specific account and not on any of the other accounts or incognito mode.

Comment: Unclear. Which Windows version? Are both computers on the same version? I don't see a difference in image quality in your image. On my Windows 11, I don't have either "More like this".

Comment: @harrymc Well it is not specifically named that, but the section below the image you clicked where it shows more images of the same. We are both running Windows 11. but it seems like this issue is on the google account itself. A setting or something that does that. Tried with 3 other google accounts and it is not happening on those, including incognito mode it doesn't happen. That is the only account with Google One subscription though.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It was signed in on Galaxy S23 (not the problem), it was ALSO signed in on Galaxy S23 Chrome Web View, I've signed out of the web view under `https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity` (This was the problem), How? Just how did you know or connect this!? Thank you so so much!

Comment: @Pierre. glad it helped! That will be made into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the account tied to a device with low-resolution, such as a cell phone? Google sets display according to the perceived device resolution, so if the account is opened with such a display, it only sends low-res screens.

Check the user account information.

BTW, go to a site such as [Browser resolution Tester](https://mdigi.tools/browser-resolution/) to see what your system *sends* to a web site, or the User Agent String can be seen at [Cover Your Tracks](https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/). If you vary this information, e.g., with browser add-on [User Agent Switcher and Manager](https://add0n.com/useragent-switcher.html), web pages from most sites will be displayed according to that data, and will appear differently in the browser.